# Different web domain and hosting

Tags: html, css, dns, hosting

I have domain 'A' with no hosting. I have domain 'B' with hosting.

I want domain 'A' to simply have a background image which it is referencing from domain 'B' hosting.

I have set up a directory in domain 'B' called 'bl' Within this folder I have placed a .jpg of the background image, 'bg.jpg' and also a style.css with the css3 code for having the background image full screen.

How do I point domain 'A' to this particular folder. Are there other elements besides the style.css and .jpg that I need?

If it helps, the only thing in the style.css file is:

```
html { 
  background: url(http://mywebsite.com/bl/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Thank you kindly for your assistance.

Comment: You will need `Absolute URL`

Comment: Thank you Mr. Alien. And how do I link domain 'A' to this page. Currently when I go to mywebsite.com/bl there is no page there.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you will need to provide absolute path for your image with domain B. This way, you can call it on domain A.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

And how do I call it, I am still not understanding how to tell 'A' to go to the particular directory in 'B'

Comment: Can you provide me with both of domain names? I will simplify for you the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing - Stackoverflow</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html {
        background-image: url('http://blogsbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Spring-Wallpaper.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
    .content {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 60%;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <h1>Hi! Is This Usefull</h1>
    <p>You can use any image that in the world wide web site. I just do it for give you more example. Just copy this code and create a new html page in your localhost. I got that image from google search. You need to get the image full path.</p>
    <p><strong>Example : </strong></p>
    <p><a href="http://blogsbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Spring-Wallpaper.jpg" target="_blank">http://blogsbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Spring-Wallpaper.jpg</a></p>
    <p>This is the url that wich I viewed from google search engine. Click on it to view the image. Do the CSS styles also what type of you like</p>
    <p>Hope you can understand this.</p>
    <small>Wish you good luck on programming</small>
    <p><small>Yeshan Sachitha K Perera @ ITSthe1</small></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Create new html document in your localhost with this source code and run it. I hope you can understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the existence of Domain B. It is irrelevant.

You need to:

1. Configure the DNS for Domain A to point at the IP address of the server which is running the webserver
2. Create (in the web server configuration) a new [Virtual Name Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) (that's the Apache documentation, if you don't use Apache you'll need to find the appropriate docs for your server) with a DocumentRoot pointing to that directory (on the file system. the existence of B is still irrelevent!)
3. Add an index.html file (you have to have a webpage for the background image to appear on).